# Boolean Expression in XML statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

good evening.
I have two questions: 
1) How can I represent boolean expressions in XML? 
example:

```
<service> 
<rule> </rule> and <rule> </rule> 
<rule> </rule> or <rule> </rule> 
</service>
```

OK, I'll explain my problem. 
I want to implement an inference engine. 
The problem is as follows: 
service has a set of actions and each action has a set of rules. 
rules can be linked by logical operators. 
I thought about using XML to represent my rules. Knowing rule X I want to extract all the actions associated with this rule.
For example

```
action=admin_required, service=identity, rules=[role:admin or is_admin:1]
action=service_role, service=, rules=[role:service]
action=get_service, service=identity, rules=[admin_required or service_role]
action=list_services, service=identity, rules=[admin_required and admin_service]
action=create_service, service=identity, rules=[admin_required]
action=update_service, service=identity, rules=[admin_required]
```

best regards

Comment: Please post your questions separately, as they seem unrelated to each other. -- Hint: spend a little more time and effort explaining what you need, esp. *why* you need it.

Comment: To add additional information do I change the question or add as a response?

Comment: The answer to your question is "any way you like". It really depends on what (or who) is on the receiving side and what do they need to do with this information. Of that you have told us practically nothing - but any format that enables them to do their job will do. That's what the X (eXtensible) in XML stands for. -- P.S. See also [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) as a possible standard.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's way beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, but I guess I would do:

```
<service>
    <match>all</match>
    <rule>...</rule>
    <rule>...</rule>
</service>
```

with `match` being `all` or `any`. Or you could have that as an attribute of `service`.

Not sure I understand your second question, care to elaborate?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, although conceptually, *all/any* is not a sibling of rules, but rather an attribute of their parent - so why not to make it so in form too.

Comment: i have change my question.
best regards

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no "best" way, but one way could be to have an **operator** element to link two rules, or maybe other operators. For example, your first rule `rules=[role:admin or is_admin:1]` could be expressed as so

```
  <rules>
     <operator type="or">
        <rule>role:admin</rule>
        <rule>is_admin:1</rule>
     </operator>
  </rules>
```

This would allow 'nested' operators too. For example `rules=[role:admin or (is_admin:1 and role:tester)]` could be expressed as

```
  <rules>
     <operator type="or">
        <rule>role:admin</rule>
        <operator type="or">
           <rule>is_admin:1</rule>
           <rule>role:tester</rule>
       </operator>
     </operator>
  </rules>
```

You've tagged this XSLT, so here is some XSLT that can be used to 'parse' the rules. It does so for by matching **operator** elements, and then recursively parsing the first and second operands. Then, it gives the result depending on the operator type. The **rule** elements are simply parsed by checking if the rule exists in the parameter holding all rules.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="rules">role:admin</xsl:param>
   <xsl:variable name="checkrule" select="concat(',', $rules, ',')" />

   <xsl:template match="actions">
      <results>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </results>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="action">
      <xsl:variable name="evaluate">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="rules/*" mode="rules" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="$evaluate=1">
         <xsl:value-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="operator" mode="rules">
      <xsl:variable name="left">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="rules" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="right">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]" mode="rules" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@type='or'">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$left=1 or $right=1">1</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="@type='and'">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$left=1 and $right=1">1</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="rule" mode="rules">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($rules, .)">1</xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML (representing all your actions)

```
<actions>
   <action name="admin_required">
      <rules>
         <operator type="or">
            <rule>role:admin</rule>
            <rule>is_admin:1</rule>
         </operator>
      </rules>
   </action>
   <action name="service_role">
      <rules>
            <rule>role:service</rule>
      </rules>
   </action>
   <action name="get_service">
      <rules>
         <operator type="or">
            <rule>admin_required</rule>
            <rule>admin_service</rule>
         </operator>
      </rules>
   </action>
   <action name="list_services">
      <rules>
         <operator type="and">
            <rule>admin_required</rule>
            <rule>admin_service</rule>
         </operator>
      </rules>
   </action>
   <action name="create_service">
      <rules>
            <rule>admin_required</rule>
      </rules>
   </action>
   <action name="update_service">
      <rules>
            <rule>admin_required</rule>
      </rules>
   </action>
</actions>
```

The following is output

```
<results>admin_required;</results>
```

If you want a 'recursive' solution, try this XSLT, which uses a named template that is called recursively with the results of the previous call.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="rules">role:admin</xsl:param>
   <xsl:variable name="checkrule" select="concat(',', $rules, ',')"/>

   <xsl:template match="actions">
      <results>
         <xsl:call-template name="recursive"/>
      </results>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="recursive">
      <xsl:param name="currentRules" select="$rules"/>
      <xsl:param name="currentResults"/>
      <xsl:variable name="newResults">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="action">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentRules" select="$currentRules"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$newResults != $currentResults">
            <xsl:call-template name="recursive">
               <xsl:with-param name="currentRules" select="concat($rules, ';', $newResults)"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="currentResults" select="$newResults"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentResults"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="action">
      <xsl:param name="currentRules"/>
      <xsl:variable name="evaluate">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="rules/*" mode="rules">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentRules" select="$currentRules"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="$evaluate=1">
         <xsl:value-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="operator" mode="rules">
      <xsl:param name="currentRules"/>
      <xsl:variable name="left">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]" mode="rules">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentRules" select="$currentRules"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="right">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[2]" mode="rules">
            <xsl:with-param name="currentRules" select="$currentRules"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@type='or'">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$left=1 or $right=1">1</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="@type='and'">
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="$left=1 and $right=1">1</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="rule" mode="rules">
      <xsl:param name="currentRules"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="contains($currentRules, .)">1</xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following result

```
<results>admin_required;get_service;create_service;update_service;</results>
```

Comment: As you see the roles are recursive. how I can implement recursion in XSLT? for example if i put in xsl:param "rules" the value "role:admin" xslt have to say there is 2 actions related to this rule : admin_required and list_service
best regards

Comment: At the moment, you would have to call the XSLT multiple times, with the new parameters being the result of the previous call.

Comment: so there isn't a way to get all action by recursion call?
Best regards